# Accessing sharepoint folder from python script scheduled via Windows Task Scheduler on Microsoft Service Account

Tags: python, sharepoint, scheduled-tasks

I have a python script that monitors a folder on our company sharepoint and moves files.
I would like to run this automatically on a daily basis and therefore setup a task within the windows scheduler.

We have a service account for tasks like this.
I setup the task properly with the option selected to be run whether the user is logged off or in.
This works properly as long as the folder to be monitored is a local one.
When I change it to the sharepoint location that is supposed to be monitored the task runs and gives the return code: `Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\MonitoringSharepoint" , action "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" with return code 2147942401.` 
And nothing happens.

For the record the service account has full access to the sharepoint folder to be monitored.

I suspect that the issue is somehow the way I am refering to that sharepoint location, which looks like so in the script: `rootdir = ("//sharepoint.company.com/sites/projects/")`
If I run this script manually it works fine, but I am not very experience with this sort of stuff and assume that this relative way of refering to the sharepoint location doesnt work when it is being run from a service account that is not logged in?

I looked into different ways of accessing sharepoint via python and tried my luck on the requests api but I had no luck so far. Authentication to our sharepoint works via sso.
I tried api calls like this one:

```
https://sharepoint.company.com/sites/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/projects')
```

but if I put that into the browser I get a No webpage was found for the web address 404 error.

Comment: your api url is not proper it should (e.g {siteurl/_api/web/methods}) https://sharepoint.company.com/sites/_api/web/

Comment: @JayneshSharma Thanks for the response, but I am not sure I understand, how is the url you wrote different from the one I have above? I took this one directly from the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service